# Xorg freezing up completely. "The NVIDIA X driver has encountered an error..." in Xorg logs, "NVRM: GPU at PCI..." in syslog

Tags: nvidia, kernel, xorg, freeze, gpu

**TL;DR**: My system kept freezing up completely - no mouse, keyboard etc. Screen was completely frozen. I thought it had to do with the file system, but it was a problem with my Nvidia driver. I tried switching from Unity to `xfce4`, but random freezes still occur. Still trying to work out what's happening.

---

I recently installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04 on my old laptop and wanted to copy some files onto it from my external hard-drive (Seagate 4TB SRD0NF1). So I plugged in my hard-drive, navigated to the folder with nautilus, and then just before being able to copy it everything froze. No ability to move the mouse - completely frozen. So I shut down by holding the power button and tried again a few times, and it froze a few more times, but the last time I managed to copy about 10% of the files (there are about 160,000 files in total) onto my desktop before it froze again.

So I thought it was some strange error in the way Linux was handling the external hard-drive, but then, after rebooting and disconnecting the hard-drive, I decided to open up the folder to see which files had managed to be copied across. And Ubuntu froze again.

<s>So now I'm thinking it has something to do with the files themselves, but I have no idea. They're nested very deeply, and there's probably some very long filenames in there, if that matters (I remember Windows having trouble with this sort of thing)</s> (See edit). Here's my syslog right before it crashes:

```
Jan 29 21:22:49 joe-l502x dbus[910]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jan 29 21:22:49 joe-l502x systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 29 21:22:49 joe-l502x dbus[910]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 29 21:22:49 joe-l502x systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 29 21:22:49 joe-l502x org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1687]: ** (process:2120): WARNING **: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/2 (g-dbus-error-quark, 
19)
Jan 29 21:22:51 joe-l502x kernel: [  231.057723] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-e89c676b-485a-4551-fc4f-e23db62c065d
Jan 29 21:22:51 joe-l502x kernel: [  231.057736] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 32, Channel ID 00000003 intr 80804000
Jan 29 21:22:52 joe-l502x kernel: [  231.059903] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 62, !18bc(0ed4)
Jan 29 21:22:52 joe-l502x org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1687]: ** (gvfsd:1758): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused
Jan 29 21:22:52 joe-l502x org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1687]: ** (process:2374): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Jan 29 21:22:55 joe-l502x org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1687]: ** (gvfsd:1758): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused
Jan 29 21:22:55 joe-l502x org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1687]: ** (process:2391): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Jan 29 21:22:55 joe-l502x kernel: [  235.057714] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 32, Channel ID 00000003 intr 80804000
```

I'm a linux noob so I really have no idea what's going on in those logs there. Anybody have any clues as to what's happening here? <s>Something to do with this "dbus" thing?</s> Any other logs I should look at? Thanks!

## Edit 1:

Okay, so it looks like it has something to do with those GPU messages. Here's another crash:

```
<< FREEZES HERE >>
Jan 29 21:52:22 joe-l502x kernel: [   90.715448] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-e89c676b-485a-4551-fc4f-e23db62c065d
Jan 29 21:52:22 joe-l502x kernel: [   90.715457] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics SM Warp Exception on (GPC 0, TPC 0): Illegal Instruction Encoding
Jan 29 21:52:22 joe-l502x kernel: [   90.715466] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics SM Global Exception on (GPC 0, TPC 0): Physical Multiple Warp Errors
Jan 29 21:52:22 joe-l502x kernel: [   90.715472] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x504648=0x9 0x504650=0x4 0x504644=0x1beff2 0x50464c=0xf
Jan 29 21:52:22 joe-l502x kernel: [   90.715494] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics SM Warp Exception on (GPC 0, TPC 1): Illegal Instruction Encoding
Jan 29 21:52:22 joe-l502x kernel: [   90.715500] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics SM Global Exception on (GPC 0, TPC 1): Physical Multiple Warp Errors
Jan 29 21:52:22 joe-l502x kernel: [   90.715506] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x504e48=0x9 0x504e50=0x4 0x504e44=0x1beff2 0x504e4c=0xf
Jan 29 21:52:22 joe-l502x kernel: [   90.715526] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ChID 0001, Class 00009197, Offset 00000100, Data 0fffcc00
Jan 29 21:52:58 joe-l502x systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 108...
Jan 29 21:52:58 joe-l502x systemd[1163]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 29 21:52:58 joe-l502x systemd[1163]: Stopped target Default.
Jan 29 21:52:59 joe-l502x systemd[1163]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jan 29 21:52:59 joe-l502x systemd[1163]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jan 29 21:52:59 joe-l502x systemd[1163]: Stopped target Paths.
Jan 29 21:52:59 joe-l502x systemd[1163]: Stopped target Timers.
Jan 29 21:52:59 joe-l502x systemd[1163]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jan 29 21:52:59 joe-l502x systemd[1163]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 2399 (kill).
Jan 29 21:52:59 joe-l502x systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 108.
Jan 29 21:52:59 joe-l502x systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.
```

And this doesn't seem to be specific to nautilius ("Files"). Here's the crash message I get when opening with the "Thunar" file explorer:

```
Jan 29 22:08:50 joe-l502x kernel: [  843.694898] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-e89c676b-485a-4551-fc4f-e23db62c065d
Jan 29 22:08:50 joe-l502x kernel: [  843.694903] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 44, Ch 00000001, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
Jan 29 22:08:50 joe-l502x kernel: [  844.196602] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 39, CCMDs 00000007 000090b5
```

Navigating to the folder and copying via the terminal works fine, so this doesn't appear to be something specifically to do with the file system.

My graphics card is a Nvidia GTX 540M, and my driver is version 384.111.

## Edit 2:

And actually, I recall a similar freeze happening when I was using the unity tweak tool GUI a couple of weeks back. So this may have something to do with Unity? Or Xorg?

## Edit 3:

Confirmed that this very likely has nothing to do with the file system. I just got the freeze while in the Ubuntu `System Settings > Software & Updates` GUI. Very similar logs:

```
Jan 30 06:33:51 joe-l502x kernel: [30264.899235] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-e89c676b-485a-4551-fc4f-e23db62c065d
Jan 30 06:33:51 joe-l502x kernel: [30264.899241] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: Shader Program Header 6 Error
Jan 30 06:33:51 joe-l502x kernel: [30264.899245] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: Shader Program Header 9 Error
Jan 30 06:33:51 joe-l502x kernel: [30264.899248] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: Shader Program Header 18 Error
Jan 30 06:33:51 joe-l502x kernel: [30264.899252] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x405840=0xa0040240
Jan 30 06:33:51 joe-l502x kernel: [30264.899267] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ChID 0001, Class 00009197, Offset 00000100, Data 0fffcc00
```

Definitely seems like it has to do with the interaction between my GPU and some Linux GUI library/thing.

## Edit 4:

Someone directed me to `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` and I think this basically confirms 100% that it's the nvidia driver playing up:

```
[ 30246.723] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[ 30246.723] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[ 30246.723] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 30246.723] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 30246.723] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[ 30246.723] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[ 30246.723] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 30246.723] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 30267.150] (EE) NVIDIA(0): The NVIDIA X driver has encountered an error; attempting to
[ 30267.150] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     recover...
<< but it never recovers :( >>
```

Comment: Done. Note that, as mentioned above, the error has occurred when the hard-drive isn't even connected.

Comment: What does your internal drive look like? Is it by chance an SSD or Hybrid?

Comment: Yeah, it's a 960gb ssd (SanDisk SDSSDXPS960G). Per edit #2, I'm now thinking it might be something more general - perhaps to do with Unity or some Xorg thing? I had 16.04 going fine on this laptop previously but was using the open source Xorg graphics driver rather than the nvidia one. Haven't had any other hints that this nvidia driver is playing up though.

Comment: All those `NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00)` are indeed NVIDIA driver errors, not Xorg nor Unity errors.  Start looking in that direction.

Comment: Thanks! <s>Ended up switching to `xfce4` and that fixed it. No idea how unity was (directly or indirectly) triggering the error.</s> **Edit**: I spoke too soon! It just froze up with `xfce4` too. More investigating to do.

Comment: Did you find a solution?